# Dynamical fetching from database - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, dynamic

Simple problem.
I want to fetch data from database in array without knowing databse indexes. Like dynamic fetching. Let's say I want to fetch two columns from dbase named "name" and "lastname", but echo it using array without database indexes. Like shown in code below:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT name, lastname FROM employees WHERE id = '1'");

$nameX=array(); 


while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) 
{ 
$nameX=$myrow;
}  


foreach ($nameX as $bla)
    {
        echo $bla;
    }
```

After this code is run it will echo:
JonJonSnowSnow
for the Jon Snow in database as name and lastname.
Little help?

Comment: `MYSQL_NUM` or `MYSQL_ASSOC`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php also read the BIG RED WARNING

Comment: Yeah, mysql_query() and mysql_fetch_array() are deprecated. Don't use them.

Comment: *Without knowing database indexes -> How are you going to use "name, lastname" in sql query. I'd suggest you to use the same methodology to store records in $nameX[$column] array.

Comment: Yes,PDO is much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It didn't seem to me a good practice, just relay your model consistency on a dynamic fetching. However I think it could be done using PDO (what is, by the way, a better to implement data acess). 
This code probably will help you:

```
$pdo = new PDO("host;dbname", "user", "pass");
$sql = "SELECT name, lastname FROM employees WHERE id = :id;";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
if($stmt) {
    while(($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) !== false) {
        foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
            echo($value);
        }
    }                  
}
```